# Spring Boot JSP 404.Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: jsp, spring-boot, http-status-code-404

Can't load a very simple JSP page with spring-boot, getting 404 Not Found

HmisApplication.class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HmisApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(HmisApplication.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(HmisApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

MainController.java

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {
@RequestMapping("/")
public String home(Map<String, Object> model) {
    model.put("message", "HowToDoInJava Reader !!");
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping("/next")
public String next(Map<String, Object> model) {
    model.put("message", "You are in new page !!");
    return "next";
}
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=dev,build-info

server.contextPath=/hmis
server.port=7070
spring.metrics.export.enabled=true

spring.main.banner-mode=off

spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
application.message: Hello Phil

# HTTP encoding (HttpEncodingProperties)
spring.http.encoding.force-request=true
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.hmis</groupId>
<artifactId>hmis</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>hmis</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic</artifactId>
        <version>5.21.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Tomcat Embed -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- To compile JSP files -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

MvcConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    registry.viewResolver(resolver);
}
}
```

File Structure

```
        ├── src
        ├── main
        │   ├── java
        │   │   └── com
        │   │       └── hmis
        │   │             ├── HmisApplication.java
        │   │             ├── MvcConfiguration.java
        │   │             ├── WelcomeController.java  
        │   └── resources
        │       └── application.properties
        │       └── webapp
        │             └── WEB-INF
        │                   └── jsp
        │                         └── index.jsp
        │                         └── next.jsp
```

Comment: spring boot already provides InternalResourceViewResolver resolver. please try removing MvcConfiguration class completely.

Comment: I get this error message                                                                          There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not resolve view with name 'next' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Comment: move webapp folder to src/main/webapp, not under resources folder.

Comment: It does not help

Answer (score 5):

I solved problem after some changes in the pom.xml. Comment out the `scope` tag of the `tomcat-embed-jasper` dependency.

```
<groupId>com.hmis</groupId>
<artifactId>hmis</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>hmis</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic</artifactId>
        <version>5.21.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Tomcat Embed -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- To compile JSP files -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks, dude! Saved my day.
For others: here <scope>provided</scope> for "tomcat-embed-jasper" is commented.

Answer (score 2):

I got the jsp page displayed with following. I am using IntelliJ Ultimate.

**1**. Created webapp, WEB-INF, jsp directories like src -> main -> webapp -> WEB-INF ->jsp

**2**. Placed the jsp page(login.jsp) wanted to render at src -> main -> webapp -> WEB-INF -> jsp ->login.jsp

Screen shot below for quick ref

[image]:

**3**. Added following to the application.properties file:

```
   spring.mvc.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/jsp/
   spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp
```

**4**. Commented out version from `tomcat-embed-jasper` dependency in pom.xml

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
   <!--        <version>10.0.2</version>-->
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issues while working with JSP, and it was just returning Whitelabel Error, on accessing any endpoint, even there was endpoint, it was still returning Whitelabel Error Page.
The Problem is that JSP has some [limitations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations):

- With Tomcat it should work if you use war packaging, i.e. an executable war will work, and will also be deployable to a standard container (not limited to, but including Tomcat). An executable jar will not work because of a hard coded file pattern in Tomcat.
- Jetty does not currently work as an embedded container with JSPs.

So, the solution is to use
war packaging inside pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>
  <properties>
   <!-- Properties -->
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- dependencies -->
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

After that just run a simple `java -jar file.war` command and it should work now.